# Output of this given C program

Tags: c

The following program fragment

```
int k=-7;

printf("%d",0<!k);
```

will print 0 according to the answer.

Can anyone explain me why ?

Comment: Instead of according to answer, you should run the program yourself and check the value. You may be also interested in printing the values of `!k`, `!0`, `!100`, `!-1` etc. and `0 < 0`, `0 <= 0` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any value other than 0 is true. so -7 or -8 or *n* or *-k* will be true.

In your code..

```
int k=-7; // ok
```

in second line

```
0<!k
```

**!(any Integer) will always give zero.** so , !(k) = 0.

now the expression will become `0 < 0`

0 > 0 or 0 < 0 is always false.

and in `printf` statement `"%d"` is used which is Integer Specifier and output is false so you will see output 0.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

So here's what you're printing:

```
0 < !(-7)
```

First, !(-7) will give 0, because -7 is a "truthy" integer, i.e. it is non-zero, and `!` negates it, so the whole thing is "false" i.e. 0.

Then you have:

```
0 < 0
```

Which is of course false, i.e. 0 in C.  You print that as an integer, so of course you see `0`.

Answer (score -2):

```
(-7) != 0
So  !-7 = false = 0 
So   0 < !k =>  0 < 0  => false  = 0
```

Comment: @Abdul It mean  print the char your input until you input the 'x'(x not print)